# No exact matches in call to initializer error message in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm confused. Could someone please tell me why I get a "No exact matches in call to initializer" error when I have this code....

```
    let bill = textField.text
    let billTotal = Double(bill)
```

but when I force unwrap textField.text the error goes away and everything is good...

```
    let bill = textField.text!
    let billTotal = Double(bill)
```

My thinking is that it should still work without force unwrapping but the app will crash if the textField is nil.

Also, why can I not use an optional instead of force unwrapping?

```
 let bill = textField.text?
 let billTotal = Double(bill)
```

Using an optional gives me the same error: "No exact matches in call to initializer"

Comment: `textField.text` already an optional

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The error occurs because `text` is an optional and the initializer parameter must be non-optional.

> My thinking is that it should still work without force unwrapping but the app will crash if the textField is nil.

In this case force unwrapping is fine because the `text` property of a `UITextField` is never `nil` although it's declared as optional.

But instead you should check the created `Double` because the entered text might be not convertible to `Double`, either with a default value

```
let billTotal = Double(textField.text!) ?? 0.0
```

or providing a more advanced error handling

```
if let billTotal = Double(textField.text!) {
    // do something with billTotal
} else {
    // handle the error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`textField.text` already an optional.. you can do

```
 if let bill = textField.text {
      let billTotal = Double(bill)
      }
```

Also you can do that by suggested By @Jessy Thanks ...

```
let billTotal = textField.text.flatMap(Double.init)
```

To convert in Double .. its inializer takes `S : StringProtocol` which confirm `StringProtocol` ... Only the `String` and
 `Substring` types in the standard library are valid conforming types not `Optional String`

Comment: Good answer, but that initializer is failiable too. So `textField.text.flatMap(Double.init)` is the way to make `billTotal`.